# Handle Intent VIEW typ=audio/mpeg 

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

So idea is i am opening a file using apps that are already pre-installed on the device. 
Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(fileUri);
intent.setType(mimeType);
startActivity(intent);
```

And my error message is

```
08-25 12:50:32.900: E/AndroidRuntime(19555): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=audio/mpeg }
```

Any ideas how to approach this? I read about intent filters, but the guy from here told me that if I am going to use other apps to open my files then I don't need to specify any filters, is it true?

P.S. for some reason it opens PDF files just fine, and JPG and TXT

Thanks
Dennis xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas how to approach this?

Install an app on your phone that has an activity that handles this MIME type. Not every possible MIME type will be handled by the apps already on your device.

If you think that such-and-so app on your device ought to be able to handle this, use [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore&hl=en) to examine its  manifest and see where you are going wrong (e.g., `fileUri` is using an unsupported scheme).

Comment: Just to finish it off - I would recommend using intent.setDataAndType rather than intent.setData followed by intent.setType.

Comment: @Dennis: Oh, yes, I totally missed that. `setType()` will wipe out your `Uri` that you passed to `setData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the supported media formats [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Make sure you are using one of those.